# WinMerge file filter to only include specific folders?

Tags: winmerge, filefilter

I am trying to compare directories recursively but only want to include specific subfolders but fail to get the proper regex setup.

I only want to show contents from subfolders in a tree in folders local and default. So far I tried a few permutations like this:

```
name: Splunk configuration files
desc: Only include local and default folders contents

def: exclude

#d: \\*$ ## Subfolders
d: \\local\\
d: \\&\\local\\
d: \\&\\local
d: local
d: .*local.*
```

All these seem to render an empty list of files where I would expect at least one deliberately induced changed file to show up, which does show up when I don't use a filter.